# AngularJs + php authentication

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Hi i started learning AngularJs and now im trying to do my Login module using angular and php, but i have some issues. I have watched alot tutorials but none of them was helpful in my case, so here is what i have: controllers.js:

```
var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);     

controllers.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', 'UserService', function(scope, $http, User) {
scope.main = [
    {username: '', password: ''}
]

scope.login = function(){
    var config = {
        url: '../auth/login.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            username: scope.main.username,
            password: scope.main.password
        },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }

    $http(config)
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        if(data.status){
            //succefull login
            User.isLogged = true;
            User.username = data.username;
        }
        else{
            User.isLogged = false;
            User.username = '';
        }
    })
    .error(function(data,status,headers,config){
        User.isLogged = false;
        User.username = '';
    });
}
}])
```

auth.js:

```
var services = angular.module('services', []);

services.factory('UserService', [function(){
    var sdo = {
        isLogged: false,
        username: ''
    };
    return sdo;
}]);
```

login.php:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
if($username){
    return "Logged";
}else{
    return false;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" id="loginCol" ng-controller="loginController">
   <form ng-submit='login()' name="form" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
         <input type="text" ng-model="scope.main.username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Име..." />
         <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
         <input type="password" ng-model="scope.main.password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Парола..." />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group pull-right">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

In this case i want just if user type something in the username input and hit the login button and on successful call of login.php to return some message. The problem is that code written like that got error "'loginController' is not a function, got undefined" how to fix it?

Comment: You should work through the Angular tutorial as well as some video training from egghead.io. Your question shows a lack of knowledge of the framework, which is essential to have

Comment: Yea i know but there is no video tutorial that actually show how to do simple login there is articles for authentication but i can't understand them, that is why i asked here. If you can show me some tutorials i will be glad to read or watch them.

Comment: Some short introduction videos to specific techniques: http://egghead.io/lessons

A tutorial to introduce the frameworks workflow: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: how to create php file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**(Disclosure: I'm one of the developers of UserApp)**

You could try the third-party service [UserApp](https://www.userapp.io), together with the [AngularJS module](https://github.com/userapp-io/userapp-angular).

Check out the [getting started guide](https://github.com/userapp-io/userapp-angular), or take the [course on Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-v2b3k). Here's some examples of how it works:

- **Login form with error handling:**

  ```
  <form ua-login ua-error="error-msg">
      <input name="login" placeholder="Username"><br>
      <input name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"><br>
      <button type="submit">Log in</button>
      <p id="error-msg"></p>
  </form>
  ```
- **Signup form with error handling:**

  ```
  <form ua-signup ua-error="error-msg">
    <input name="first_name" placeholder="Your name"><br>
    <input name="login" ua-is-email placeholder="Email"><br>
    <input name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"><br>
    <button type="submit">Create account</button>
    <p id="error-msg"></p>
  </form>
  ```

  `ua-is-email` means that the username is the same as the email.
- **How to specify which routes that should be public, and which route that is the login form:**

  ```
  $routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html', public: true, login: true});
  $routeProvider.when('/signup', {templateUrl: 'partials/signup.html', public: true});
  ```

  The `.otherwise()` route should be set to where you want your users to be redirected after login. Example:

  `$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});`
- **Log out link:**

  `<a href="#" ua-logout>Log Out</a>`
- **Access user properties:**

  User info is accessed using the `user` service, e.g: `user.current.email`

  Or in the template: `<span>{{ user.email }}</span>`
- **Hide elements that should only be visible when logged in:**

  `<div ng-show="user.authorized">Welcome {{ user.first_name }}!</div>`
- **Show an element based on permissions:**

  `<div ua-has-permission="admin">You are an admin</div>`

And to authenticate to your back-end services, just use `user.token()` to get the session token and send it with the AJAX request. At the back-end, use the [UserApp API](https://app.userapp.io/#/docs/) with the [PHP library](https://app.userapp.io/#/docs/libs/php/) to check if the token is valid or not.

If you need any help, just let me know :)

Comment: Not going to lie.... this actually looks like a great place to begin with for any startup Angular app. Will definitely consider this in a few major projects I have coming up.

Answer (score 3):

You have created the application

```
var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);
```

but didn't use it in the html code, add ng-app attribute to the wrapper div

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-app="controllers" id="loginCol" ng-controller="loginController">
```

the second issue, that you try to catch submit event, but don't submit the form, use `submit` type instead `button`

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
```

or add `ng-click="login()"` attribute to the button and remove `ng-submit='login()'` from the form

Comment: yea the arror gone but now when i hit login nothing happend